# C++ Visual Studio- Empty For Loop in Operator Overload causes debug error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, for-loop, operator-overloading, visual-studio-debugging

I ran a for loop inside an overloaded operator and Visual Studio raised a debug error and can't resolve. When I remove the for loop, it runs perfectly; I used the exact loop in another functioning operator and there was no problem.

How can an empty for loop crash visual studio debugger?

Note: As I said, without this for loop, the program does not crash, so I assume the main() loop and class definition can not possibly have any relevance and therefore omitted them. If I'm wrong about that, I can certainly include them.

```
Account& Account::operator=(char *string){

    for (int i; i < 10; i++) {

        cout << i;

    }

    return (*this);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious thing is that you don't initialize i.  Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

Comment: Woah yeah. That was it. And my other operator wasn't being called from main to verify. I'm so stupid haha.